# Show that in an integral right angled triangle, area is not perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that in an integral right angled triangle, area is not perfect square.

I tried a few things, one of the being using the stereotype pythagoras form of the number, and tried drawing a few squares, but that didn't help a bit. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume that 
$$ a=2pq,\qquad b=p^2-q^2,\qquad c=p^2+q^2 $$
with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p,q$ not both odd. The area of the right triangle is:
$$ S = pq(p^2-q^2), $$
but since the three terms in the RHS are mutually coprime, the only chance in order that $S$ is a square is that both $p,q$ and $p^2-q^2$are squares, say $p=u^2,q=v^2,p^2-q^2=w^2$. However, the last conditions lead to an infinite descent (from $p=u^2$ and $p^2=w^2+q^2$ we have that $p$ is at the same time a square and the sum of two squares). This is essentially the same argument Fermat used to prove that
$$ a^4+b^4 = c^4 $$
has no integer solutions (case $n=4$ of the FLT).

Comment: I understood that $w,q,p$ are the sides of a shorter right angled triangle. But I did not understand how its area is a perfect square,i.e., $\frac{wq}{2}=k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$... so that the argument of the infinite descent can be used.